# codeigniter get where with two same values

Tags: codeigniter

we want search data from sales table where , payment_status is pending . i try  -

```
$this->datatables
        ->select("id, date, reference_no, biller, customer, sale_status")
        ->from('sales')
        ->where('due_date <=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('payment_status =', 'pending')
```

it work good , but when we want search both value of payment_status , pending & partial at same time it not work. i try this code-

```
$this->datatables
        ->select("id, date, reference_no, biller, customer, sale_status, grand_total, paid, (grand_total-paid) as balance, payment_status")
        ->from('sales')
        ->where('due_date <=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('payment_status =', 'pending')
        ->where('payment_status =', 'partial');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you get an error? The wrong values?

Comment: no , i found no data

Comment: That's actually quite plausible. Are you sure you actually have data that answers all three conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `or_where`

```
$this->datatables
        ->select("id, date, reference_no, biller, customer, sale_status, grand_total, paid, (grand_total-paid) as balance, payment_status")
        ->from('sales')
        ->where('due_date <=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('payment_status =', 'pending')
        ->or_where('payment_status =', 'partial');
```

It make you condition `where (payment_status ='pending' OR payment_status ='partial' )`

Comment: @princekumar This answer will get all record which has  payment_status partial does not matter due date.Check if that is OK with you.